building a saltstack proxy tool used to execute commands in a multimaster model
I am supposed to set up syndic peers that are class A masters and minions are connected in a multimaster set-up. A proxy tools is to be built that can route the command to the right master for it to be executed in a dynamic minion scenario...how do I go about this?
what will the techstack of this tool be,
what will the logic of determining the correct master for a target minion be and where would this be written?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Build a tool that can accept a given Salt command for a set of target minions, determine the correct Salt master (in a syndicate scenario), and execute the command against the specified minions. This tool will act as a proxy between the user and the multiple Salt masters, simplifying the process of executing commands across multiple Salt masters and their minions.

You reach to the proxy and send some command. The proxy in turn may reach out to multiple backends over http with some token (could be your backend which figures out where minions are connected, and actually executes salt calls / jobs) . Backend can be your API server. Frontend can stay API server to start with (which can then interact with all other backends).
